# Switching to webview context will got exception "chrome not reachable" after resetApp

Tags: google-chrome, appium

**Environment**

```
Appium : 1.6.4
OS : Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
Node.js : 7.9.0
Android : 5.1
Device :1501-M02
API :java
Appium CLI
```

**Details**

I am using spock as test framework,with blow code:

```
class Test{
      AndroidDriver<RemoteWebElement> driver;
      DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.android();
       ........
      def setup(){
            //setup driver
              .....
             cap.setCapability(NO_RESET, "true");
         cap.setCapability(FULL_RESET, "false");
          .....
             cap.setCapability(RECREATE_CHROME_DRIVER_SESSIONS, "true");
             .......
             driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.domain.pkg");
      }

      def "test1"(){}

      def "test2"(){}

      def cleanup(){
             driver.resetApp();
      }
}
```

In eclipse,If right clicking test1 or test2->run as->junit test,both two run as expected,but if right clicking Test(class)->run as->junit test,the first test works,and the second test will throw exception:

```
  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: webview=39.0.0.0)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506
```

if replacing cleanup() with this:

def cleanup(){
         driver.quit();
  }

all works as expected,but each test will reinitialize a lot of staff which wastes huge time,
so

```
driver.resetApp()
```

not work as expected,is this a bug or do I do something wrong?

appium log like this:

```
[debug] [ADB] Running '/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","MB8DW44999999999","shell","am","force-stop","com.vsi.pd.doctor"]
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.closeApp() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/appium/app/close 200 1099 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/appium/app/launch {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.launchApp() with args: ["ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2"]
[AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[debug] [AndroidDriver] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 22
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","MB8DW44999999999","shell","am","start","-W","-n","com.vsi.pd.doctor/.MainActivity","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.launchApp() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/appium/app/launch 200 1987 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/context {"name":"WEBVIEW_com.vsi.pd.doctor"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.setContext() with args: ["WEBVIEW_com.vsi.pd.doctor","ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","MB8DW44999999999","shell","cat","/proc/net/unix"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] WEBVIEW_17929 mapped to pid 17929
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting process name for webview
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","MB8DW44999999999","shell","ps"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Parsed pid: 17929 pkg: com.vsi.pd.doctor!
[debug] [AndroidDriver] from: u0_a181,17929,274,1666480,109536,ffffffff,00000000,S,com.vsi.pd.doctor
[debug] [AndroidDriver] returning process name: com.vsi.pd.doctor
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_com.vsi.pd.doctor"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_com.vsi.pd.doctor"]
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.setContext() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/context 200 117 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/element {"using":"id","value":"login"}
[MJSONWP] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/eb87d1b86ef6331102013b50ee2c0ea4/element] with body: {"using":"id","value":"login"}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"eb87d1b86ef6331102013b50ee2c0ea4","status":100,"value":{"message":**"chrome not reachable**\n  (Session info: webview=39.0.0.0)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 4.4.0-75-generic x86_64)"}}
[JSONWP Proxy] Replacing sessionId eb87d1b86ef6331102013b50ee2c0ea4 with ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/element 200 13 ms - 269 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2/appium/app/close {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.closeApp() with args: ["ebe4a8b1-844c-49f3-9997-9bc1bc0dd8a2"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","MB8DW44999999999","shell","am","force-stop","com.vsi.pd.doctor"]
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.closeApp() result: null
```

Answer (score 0):

With new UIautomator you don't need to switch your driver to webview. It has built in capabilities to identify the elements inside webView.

Please update your Android SDK once.

Elements inside WebView will be visible in UIAutomator for Android Version 6.0+ versions. However, once you automate the script for Android 6.0+ device, you can use the same script for Android version below 6.0.

And also you can see the elements inside webView on Android 6.0+ devices using UIAutomator.